# `SwiftUI` - `EnvironmentObject`s, `EnvironmentValues` does not propagate to modally presented `UIViewController`

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

`SwiftUI`'s `EnvironmentObject`s and `EnvironmentValues` should propagate to children if view hierarchy is set properly - this seems to be true for a case of pure `SwiftUI` view hierarchy. Also true for case mixing with `UIKit` when parent view controller literally contains its children (for example; `UITabViewController`, `UINavigationController`, ...).

But modally presented `UIKit` view controller on `SwiftUI` view hierarchy does not get the environments from its parent. Here are my setups.

```
// ContentView
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabBarController()
            .environment(\.lineLimit, 3) // override default value of lineLimit
    }

}

// TabBarController
struct TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UITabBarController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        let uiViewController = UITabBarController()
        uiViewController.setViewControllers([
            UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar()),
            UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar()),
            UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar())
        ], animated: false)
        return uiViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        // For test purpose, present view controller modally
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            uiViewController.present(UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar()), animated: true)
        }
    }

}

// FooBar
struct FooBar: View {

    @Environment(\.lineLimit) var lineLimit

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .onAppear {
                print(lineLimit) // prints given environment value
            }
    }

}
```

In `TabBarController` implementation I set up three tabs with their root view `FooBar`, and it presents a modal view controller with its root view `FooBar`. `FooBar` does nothing but prints value of `lineLimit` from its `EnvironmentValues` on appear. I set `lineLimit` to 3 to override its default value. The tab components prints 3, whereas the presented view prints `nil` (which is default value).

What am I doing wrong, or is it prohibited? Weird if it is, because `sheet()` from `SwiftUI` framework does work as expected (though I cannot use this API because I need full control of `UIViewController` presentation to apply custom transition ).

Comment: Same issue, this sucks. I’m working on a UIKit app with a bunch of leaf SwiftUI views and was hoping to wrap the view hierarchy in a SwiftUI view such that all the leaf views had some common context. This is the only thing preventing that approach and I can’t even do a workaround as the environment is not manually accessible from UIKit.

Answer (score 5):

A full environment (values plus objects) can be passed to a manually created `UIHostingController` to be presented.

It is not obvious, but this technique works:

###### 1. Obtain the whole environment

```
Option a)

// In any view context (= also in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`)
@Environment(\.self) var environment

Option b)

// From `UIViewControllerRepresentableContext` in `updateUIViewController`

let environment = context.environment
```

###### 2. Re-inject it anywhere you need

```
UIHostingController(
  rootView: presentedScreen
    .environment(\.self, environment)
)
```

Comment: Just a note that .environment is applied on the View not the UIHostingController

Comment: @Petar true, thanks for mentioning it. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI's `EnvironmentObjects` and `EnvironmentValues` should propagate **ONLY to SwiftUI children views**. For other (trans-framework/API) cases we have to do this manually, like

```
struct TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.lineLimit) var lineLimit                // << here !!

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UITabBarController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        let uiViewController = UITabBarController()
        uiViewController.setViewControllers([
            UIHostingController(rootView: 
                FooBar().environment(\.lineLimit, lineLimit)),   // << here !!
            UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar()),
            UIHostingController(rootView: FooBar())
        ], animated: false)
        return uiViewController
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that for `EnvironmentValues`, but it is not a scalable way. Moreover, as I mentioned above, `sheet()` API from `SwiftUI` framework does propagate environment values to its presented sheet.

Comment: @Tack-GyuLee The environment for sheet views _only_ reads its environment from the parent when it will be _created_. Any subsequent changes in the parent environment will be visible only in the parent and its views, but not to the sheet. So, changes will _not_ be propagated to already _presented_ views (aka sheets). I don't think, this is the intended behaviour, though.

Comment: @Asperi Is this true ? As shown here https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-environment-propagation-2/ and in my experiments, the EnvrionmentValues propagate properly to UIKit views